# Configure log4j.configurationFile - Works fine, feels wierd, what is better?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm buildung a small java application (for my own ;)). I try seperate the application specific code, from code/classes which could be used by other applications.

So I build a `public abstract class MyLogger implements Logger` which provides generic functions for my logging, which therefore shouldn't have any application specific code but obviously needs to know the application specific `log4j.configuration`.

My solution works like this: In the main application class, the first thing I do is defining a `private static String` with no other purpose, then calling `System.setProperty` and reading an environment variable with the path to the applications log4j configuration file.

Directly after that I initialize the `MyLogger` itself, who automatically does a `System.getProperty` with the just set path.

Like this, my first line of code in the `public static void main(String args[])` can be `LOG.info( MyLogger.buildLogLine("Started"));` :)

Here is the start of the class a declaration:

```
public class ApplicationX{

    private static String dummyString = System.setProperty( "log4j.configurationFile", System.getenv("APPX_LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE" ) );

    private static final Logger LOG = MyLogger.getLogger( "ApplicationX" );

}
```

As mentionend in the title: this works fine, but I don't really think using the execution time of static variables is the right way to achieve this.

So: How would this be done in the "real world"?

Requirements are:

- Single Class using log4j, usable for diffrent applications but with no 
  application specific code
- Capable of logging from the start of `public static void main` from the application

*Edit*

Ok, no need for the `dummyString`, but the question stays the same:

```
public class ApplicationX{

    static{ 
    System.setProperty( "log4j.configurationFile",    System.getenv("APPX_LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE" ) );
    }
    private static final Logger LOG = MyLogger.getLogger( "ApplicationX" );

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this exactly? The logging framework is perfectly capable of configuring itself...

Comment: If your intent is to make it generic, then why are you tying yourself to log4j.  I mean "Logger" does not imply "log4j" but you seem to believe it does.  Why ?

Comment: Also it is **hugely** error prone - immediately a class is initialsed before this one is, your code will blow up.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: What do you mean with "The logging framework is perfectly capable of configuring itself"? It has a lot of options and features ( Filenames, Appenders, Loglevels) which I want to configure per Application. But I want "one" Logging Class only for all my Applications. There shouldn't be another class initialised before, because it is the "main runner".

Comment: What if you decide that you want `EviliveUtil` that is also `static` and you need that in your runner to, I don't know, parse arguments? Then you have a problem. As far as configuring itself, your logging configuration file should do exactly that - I don't see the purpose of all these gettings and settings. `System.setProperty` should never be used in production code.

Comment: Well I guess that is one reason, why I ask for a better solution ;) I'll add my requirements above...

Comment: @Erwin Smout: I'm using `import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;`

Comment: I would suggest you read about [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/). This is an abstraction layer over your logging framework. You will need to exlain in more detail what you are trying to do and why accepted best in class solutions to logging (SLF4J) don't achieve what you want to do.

Comment: If my ApplicationX should write to `pathX/ApplicationX.log` and my ApplicationY should write to`pathY/ApplicationY.log` , maybe even different formatted output, i'd still want a generic class which i can simply use in all my other classes in all my applications. Because I only want one place to import the "what-so-ever-logging-Api" and do the api-specific calls because I just need to change this one class for all applications i.e. if i want to switch from `logf4j` to `SLF4J`. So in any case: this class must "somehow" know what configuration it should use, no matter which api im actually using.